# D tachograph data stored on Driver Card (CardDriverActivity)

Tags: byte, smartcard

I'm building a small application (OOPHP) to read and extract infos stored on Driver Cards. The goal is to remotely download the .ddd files from digital tachographs and unfold the information stored for data analysis.
I'm pretty new to reading from raw binary files and I'm having troubles even with the official regulation document at hand.

I dumped the ddd as hex to take a look inside while writing my classes and it went (kinda) smooth until the CardDriverActivity crossed my path.

```
05 04 00 30 cc       //DRIVER ACTIVITY DATA
2d 22
2c 92

02 66   //FIRST RECORD
1a 94
12 a1 1a a4
12 b2
1a b4

03 0c   //SECOND RECORD
1b 11
03 12 1b 1c
03 1f
1b 21
03 7a 1b 
85 23 d7 00 72 00 66 4c 5f 45 00 03 76 01 3a 20 
00 00 e9 18 ef 10 f1 18 f3 00 f9 18 fc 01 10 19
```

As you can see I isolated the header to check File ID, signature byte and block length. Now, according to official documentation, the first 2 bytes should be an offset/index of the oldest record, the following 2 should be an offset/index to newest record (stored in a cyclic vector/buffer); then should follow a set of 12 bytes in which we should find:

```
    1.activityRecordPreviousLength (2 bytes)
    2.activityRecordLength (2 bytes)
    3.activityRecordDate (4 bytes)
    4.activityPresenceCounter (2 bytes)
    5.activityDayDistance (2 bytes)
```

My problem is that values doesn't seem to make any sense, like field 3 in epoch time gives me completely random dates and there seem to be no correlation between one field and the following one. How am i supposed to split this byte flow correctly?

Thanks in advance for reading the post. Hope someone more experienced can give a tip to sort this out.

Marco Nicotra

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? Also, can you link the official documentation, I have really hard time finding the latest version? Thank you.

Comment: I think what you are looking for (or at least the place where i got all the informations) is [ https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A32016R0799 ], which is the official European law (EUR-Lex - 32016R0799)

Answer (score 0):

possible solution:

```
 public CardDriverActivity(byte[] datos){   
    int start = 0; // indice del array de byte
    byte[] arrayorigen;
    this.activityPointerOldestDayRecord = (int) Number
            .getShort_16(Arrays.copyOfRange(datos, start, start += DriverCardSizes.ACTIVITYPOINTEROLDESTADAYRECORD.getMax()));
    this.activityPointerNewestRecord = (int) Number
            .getShort_16(Arrays.copyOfRange(datos, start, start += DriverCardSizes.ACTIVITYPOINTERNEWESTRECORD.getMax()));
    arrayorigen = Arrays.copyOfRange(datos, start, start += datos.length);
    // preparamos array de datos ya que es una grabacion ciclica y cuando
    // llega al final continua al principio
    // de los datos por lo que el inicio podria estar en medio de los datos
    byte[] arraybyte;
    if (this.activityPointerNewestRecord < this.activityPointerOldestDayRecord) {
        byte[] array1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(arrayorigen, this.activityPointerOldestDayRecord, datos.length-4);
        byte[] array2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(arrayorigen, 0, this.activityPointerNewestRecord);
        arraybyte = new byte[array1.length + array2.length];
        System.arraycopy(array1, 0, arraybyte, 0, array1.length);
        System.arraycopy(array2, 0, arraybyte, array1.length, array2.length - 1);           
    } else {
        // less 4 bytes for
        // activityPointerOldestDayRecord and acitivityPointerNewestRecord
        arraybyte = Arrays.copyOfRange(datos, this.activityPointerOldestDayRecord + 4,
                this.activityPointerNewestRecord + 4 - this.activityPointerOldestDayRecord + 4);
    }
    int length = 0;
    int indice = 0;
    CardActivityDailyRecord cadr;
    this.activityDailyRecords = new ArrayList<CardActivityDailyRecord>();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    while (indice < arraybyte.length) {
        length = Number.getShort_16(Arrays.copyOfRange(arraybyte, indice + DriverCardSizes.ACTIVITYRECORDLENGTH.getMax(),
                indice + indice + DriverCardSizes.ACTIVITYRECORDLENGTH.getMax() + DriverCardSizes.ACTIVITYRECORDLENGTH.getMax()));
        //System.out.println("length "+length+" indice:"+indice);
        byte[] arrayfrom = Arrays.copyOfRange(arraybyte, indice, indice += length);
        cadr = new CardActivityDailyRecord(arrayfrom);
        this.activityDailyRecords.add(cadr);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be PHP, looks more like Java. Anyway I thank you for the answer. Kinda abandoned the project but i think it was related to the information packaging: i was not interpreting correctly the first 5 header bytes, so they got mixed with the real information. I got it working after some headaches but i don't have access to the code anymore and it was 2 years ago. Sry :/